# Tests from non-public classes silently ignored

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, mstest

I am using Mstest v2 and run my test from within Visual Studio. If a test class is marked with `[TestClass]` but only internal, its tests are not found/ignored.

How to get a warning or even better error about such ignored tests? Otherwise one think "oh all fine", but instead of the tests having passed, they maybe were just not executed.

Comment: Don't have a solution, but an idea: Write your own code analyzer https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers or write another test, that references all test projects and check via reflection if all classes with the given attribute are public.

Comment: assuming you are using visual studio maybe you could search for all occurences of a regex pattern that does match [TestClass] newline private. But i am not able to produce this because im really bad at regex im afraid.

Comment: I've been frustrated by this as well. There doesn't appear to be a way to restrict an attribute by class and access modifier. It would be ideal to show a compiler error, or at least a warning when running tests. Doesn't look like this is possible with attributes alone. This just might be an item to check in code reviews.